# Parsing String by regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I parse this string in python?

Input String:

`someplace 2018:6:18:0 25.0114  95.2818  2.71164  66.8962    Entire grid contents are set to missing data`

to this

Output array:

`['someplace','2018:6:18:0','25.0114','95.2818','2.71164','66.8962','Entire grid contents are set to missing data']`

I have already tried with `split(' ')` but as it is not clear how many spaces are between the sub-strings and inside the last sub-string there may be spaces so this doesn't work.

I need the regular expression.

Comment: its hard to know what regular expression you want when you only give one example of input and output, depending on how consistent your data is you can do this sort of splitting with some simple string operations or you might need complex regexes , its hard to know without all of your data (or at least representative examples)

Comment: Can you give us a rule that explains how to split the string? For example, "Match anything (group 1) up to the first substring consisting only of digits and colons (group 2), then four decimal numbers (digits and periods, groups 3-6) and then the rest of the string (group 7)"

Comment: Use split() instead of split('\ '). It treats more spaces between words as one, and you can limit the number of cuts: split(maxsplit=6).

Comment: i only need the regular expression which i can use in split() method. Rule is that to ......separate the spaces between the substrings and inside the last substring .generate array according to  spaces between the substrings except last substring..... number of spaces are not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not provide a *sep*-character, pythons `split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)` [(doku)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will treat consecutive whitespaces as one whitespace and split by those. You can limit the amount of splits to be done by providing a *maxsplit* value:

```
data = "someplace 2018:6:18:0 25.0114  95.2818  2.71164  66.8962    Entire grid contents are set to missing data"

spl = data.split(None,6) # dont give a split-char, use 6 splits at most
print(spl)
```

Output:

```
['someplace', '2018:6:18:0', '25.0114', '95.2818', '2.71164', 
 '66.8962', 'Entire grid contents are set to missing data']
```

This will work as long as the first text does not contain any whitespaces.

---

If the fist text may contain whitespaces, you can use/refine this regex solution:

```
import re

reg = re.findall(r"([^\d]+?) +?([\d:]+) +?([\d.]+) +?([\d.]+) +?([\d.]+) +?([\d.]+) +(.*)$",data)[0]
print(reg)
```

Output:

```
('someplace', '2018:6:18:0', '25.0114', '95.2818', '2.71164', '66.8962', 'Entire grid contents are set to missing data')
```

Use f.e.[https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nhp8Ab/2) to check/proof the regex against your other data (follow the link, it uses above regex on sample data)

Answer (score 1):

[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z ]{15,45}|[\w|:|.]+

You can test it here https://pythex.org/

Modify 15,45 according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, you are right. I did not run and see the python code. I have modified answer and it should be fine now.

Comment: Be carefull with `[A-z]`, it matches character that are between `Z` and `a` ie. left opening bracket, back slash, right closing bracket, caret cirumflex, underscore, backtick. See http://table-ascii.com/

Comment: Look at `[\w|:|.]` part of the proposed regex. Both `|` chars are not needed.
Another remark: Instead of `[a-zA-Z ]` use just `[A-Z ]` but with *IGNORECASE* option.

Answer (score 1):

Maxsplit works with re.split(), too:

```
import re

re.split(r"\s+",text,maxsplit=6)
Out: 
['someplace',
 '2018:6:18:0',
 '25.0114',
 '95.2818',
 '2.71164',
 '66.8962',
 'Entire grid contents are set to missing data']
```

**EDIT:**
If the first and last text parts don't contain digits, we don't need maxsplit and do not have to rely on number of parts with consecutive spaces:

```
re.split("\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s+",s)
```

We cut the string where a space is followed by a digit or vice versa using lookahead and lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer your question as the requirements are not very precise. I think I would split the line with the split() function and then join the items when their contents has no numbers. Here is a snippet that works with your lonely sample:

```
def containsNumbers(s):
    return any(c.isdigit() for c in s)

data = "someplace 2018:6:18:0 25.0114  95.2818  2.71164  66.8962    Entire grid contents are set to missing data"
lst = data.split()
lst2 = []
i = 0
agg = ''
while i < len(lst):
    if containsNumbers(lst[i]):
        if agg != '':
            lst2.append(agg)
            agg = ''
        lst2.append(lst[i])
    else:
        agg += ' '+lst[i]
        agg = agg.strip()
        if i == len(lst) - 1:
            lst2.append(agg)
    i += 1

print(lst2)
```